# Convert Object to BuffredInputStream in JAVA

Tags: java, object, bufferedinputstream

Hi i used the below code to convert my object into Input stream. But I actually wanted to convert my object into BufferedInputStream. What changes should i make to my code ?

```
             ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
             oos.writeObject(obj);
             oos.flush();
             oos.close();
             InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
```

Comment: Just wrap `is` in a `BufferedInputStream`?

Comment: Java Doc : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html

Answer (score 0):

The [BufferedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) takes an InputStream in the constructor, so you can do it with:

```
BufferedInputStream bIn = new BufferedInputStream(is);
```

> A BufferedInputStream adds functionality to another input stream-namely, the ability to buffer the input and to support the mark and reset methods. When the BufferedInputStream is created, an internal buffer array is created. As bytes from the stream are read or skipped, the internal buffer is refilled as necessary from the contained input stream, many bytes at a time. The mark operation remembers a point in the input stream and the reset operation causes all the bytes read since the most recent mark operation to be reread before new bytes are taken from the contained input stream.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it like this:

```
new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need that convertion?

BufferedInputStream is used to buffer bytes in order to reduce quantity of invocations of external I/O operations. Since ByteArrayInputStream already keeps its data in a byte array, wrapping it in BufferedInputStream would not reduce invocations of I/O operations (there are none), but only add overhead of copying bytes from the array to the buffer.

Comment: The question was, HOW he can wrap it, not if it is a good solution.